# System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException in DNN News Feeds

Tags: xml, xslt, rss, dotnetnuke, rss-reader

I have installed an RSS reader module in DotNetNuke. I have to configure the XSL to get the output in a readable format. The RSS is as follows:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:atlassian="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/general/1.0"><id>http://oncprojectracking.org/activity?maxResults=5&amp;title=undefined</id><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/activity?maxResults=5&amp;title=undefined" rel="self" /><title type="text">undefined</title><atlassian:timezone-offset>-0400</atlassian:timezone-offset><updated>2013-07-25T19:58:16.899Z</updated><entry xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/"><id>urn:uuid:876b6dc4-7ecc-39c8-8862-d9793f1bc5b6</id><title type="html">&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson" class="activity-item-user activity-item-author">Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson&lt;/a> changed the Assignee to '&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=mhinterberg%40ofmq.com" class="activity-item-user">Michelle Hinterberg&lt;/a>' on       &lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-778">CQM-778 - CMS72v2/NQF0438 Denominator Exception for Antithrombotic Therapy not done should be limited to &amp;lt;=1 day after start of Non-Elective Inpatient Encounter if you don&amp;#39;t have an ED Encounter prior to the inpatient encounter&lt;/a>
  </title><author xmlns:usr="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/username/1.0"><name>Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson</name><uri>http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</uri><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=16" media:height="16" media:width="16" /><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=48" media:height="48" media:width="48" /><usr:username>sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</usr:username><activity:object-type>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/person</activity:object-type></author><published>2013-07-25T18:57:37.443Z</published><updated>2013-07-25T18:57:37.443Z</updated><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-778" rel="alternate" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/images/icons/issuetypes/genericissue.png" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/icon" title="Logic" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/s/en_US-46i7uf-1988229788/6099/7/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:global-static/wiki-renderer.css" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/css" /><generator uri="http://oncprojectracking.org" /><atlassian:application>com.atlassian.jira</atlassian:application><activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/update</activity:verb><activity:object><id>urn:uuid:932c25ac-4b15-3dc2-969c-8b6fd5ce73d9</id><title type="text">CQM-778</title><summary type="text">CMS72v2/NQF0438 Denominator Exception for Antithrombotic Therapy not done should be limited to &lt;=1 day after start of Non-Elective Inpatient Encounter if you don't have an ED Encounter prior to the inpatient encounter</summary><link rel="alternate" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-778" /><activity:object-type>http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/types/issue</activity:object-type></activity:object><atlassian:timezone-offset>-0400</atlassian:timezone-offset></entry><entry xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/"><id>urn:uuid:68578e9f-2534-30d8-8bb1-86d937b8e41f</id><title type="html">&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson" class="activity-item-user activity-item-author">Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson&lt;/a> changed the Assignee to '&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=chengjianche" class="activity-item-user">Chengjian Che&lt;/a>' on       &lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-775">CQM-775 - IPP definition will exclude some patients from ever being considered.&lt;/a>
  </title><author xmlns:usr="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/username/1.0"><name>Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson</name><uri>http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</uri><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=16" media:height="16" media:width="16" /><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=48" media:height="48" media:width="48" /><usr:username>sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</usr:username><activity:object-type>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/person</activity:object-type></author><published>2013-07-25T18:54:55.077Z</published><updated>2013-07-25T18:54:55.077Z</updated><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-775" rel="alternate" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/images/icons/issuetypes/genericissue.png" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/icon" title="Logic" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/s/en_US-46i7uf-1988229788/6099/7/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:global-static/wiki-renderer.css" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/css" /><generator uri="http://oncprojectracking.org" /><atlassian:application>com.atlassian.jira</atlassian:application><activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/update</activity:verb><activity:object><id>urn:uuid:79a1ad6c-8f35-3cb3-88a0-ae77c0700953</id><title type="text">CQM-775</title><summary type="text">IPP definition will exclude some patients from ever being considered.</summary><link rel="alternate" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-775" /><activity:object-type>http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/types/issue</activity:object-type></activity:object><atlassian:timezone-offset>-0400</atlassian:timezone-offset></entry><entry xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/"><id>urn:uuid:d2c02478-7beb-3fe6-afe3-5eaf608463e5</id><title type="html">&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson" class="activity-item-user activity-item-author">Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson&lt;/a> changed the Assignee to '&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=mhinterberg%40ofmq.com" class="activity-item-user">Michelle Hinterberg&lt;/a>' on       &lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-773">CQM-773 - CMS188v3/NQF0147 Patient with Any Infection (AND) a respiratory infection will not be excluded&lt;/a>
  </title><author xmlns:usr="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/username/1.0"><name>Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson</name><uri>http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</uri><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=16" media:height="16" media:width="16" /><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=48" media:height="48" media:width="48" /><usr:username>sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</usr:username><activity:object-type>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/person</activity:object-type></author><published>2013-07-25T18:54:11.130Z</published><updated>2013-07-25T18:54:11.130Z</updated><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-773" rel="alternate" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/images/icons/issuetypes/genericissue.png" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/icon" title="Logic" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/s/en_US-46i7uf-1988229788/6099/7/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:global-static/wiki-renderer.css" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/css" /><generator uri="http://oncprojectracking.org" /><atlassian:application>com.atlassian.jira</atlassian:application><activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/update</activity:verb><activity:object><id>urn:uuid:4ef04280-a9a2-3140-ae43-a7026e199727</id><title type="text">CQM-773</title><summary type="text">CMS188v3/NQF0147 Patient with Any Infection (AND) a respiratory infection will not be excluded</summary><link rel="alternate" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-773" /><activity:object-type>http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/types/issue</activity:object-type></activity:object><atlassian:timezone-offset>-0400</atlassian:timezone-offset></entry><entry xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/"><id>urn:uuid:78aede70-9e52-3097-9797-54c70c55796d</id><title type="html">&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson" class="activity-item-user activity-item-author">Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson&lt;/a> changed the Assignee to '&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=cynthial.barton" class="activity-item-user">Cynthia L. Barton&lt;/a>' on       &lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-772">CQM-772 - CMS73 NQF373 does not include Bivalirudin in value set - can it be added?&lt;/a>
  </title><author xmlns:usr="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/username/1.0"><name>Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson</name><uri>http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</uri><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=16" media:height="16" media:width="16" /><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=48" media:height="48" media:width="48" /><usr:username>sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</usr:username><activity:object-type>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/person</activity:object-type></author><published>2013-07-25T18:52:15.883Z</published><updated>2013-07-25T18:52:15.883Z</updated><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-772" rel="alternate" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/images/icons/issuetypes/genericissue.png" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/icon" title="Logic" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/s/en_US-46i7uf-1988229788/6099/7/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:global-static/wiki-renderer.css" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/css" /><generator uri="http://oncprojectracking.org" /><atlassian:application>com.atlassian.jira</atlassian:application><activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/update</activity:verb><activity:object><id>urn:uuid:06847a8a-7012-3f11-8732-dee23020ec2d</id><title type="text">CQM-772</title><summary type="text">CMS73 NQF373 does not include Bivalirudin in value set - can it be added?</summary><link rel="alternate" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-772" /><activity:object-type>http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/types/issue</activity:object-type></activity:object><atlassian:timezone-offset>-0400</atlassian:timezone-offset></entry><entry xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/"><id>urn:uuid:b4d1ff48-05a7-35af-a018-f428605a769c</id><title type="html">&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson" class="activity-item-user activity-item-author">Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson&lt;/a> changed the Assignee to '&lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=mhinterberg%40ofmq.com" class="activity-item-user">Michelle Hinterberg&lt;/a>' on       &lt;a href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-771">CQM-771 - CMS188v3/NQF0147 Logic for No ED &amp;gt; NonICU &amp;gt; ICU path does not limit transfers to ICU to within 24hrs after arrival&lt;/a>
  </title><content type="html">&lt;blockquote>
   &lt;p>Another one for PN-6.&lt;/p>   &lt;/blockquote>
</content><author xmlns:usr="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/username/1.0"><name>Sharon J. Giarrizzo-Wilson</name><uri>http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</uri><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=16" media:height="16" media:width="16" /><link xmlns:media="http://purl.org/syndication/atommedia" rel="photo" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122&amp;s=48" media:height="48" media:width="48" /><usr:username>sharonj.giarrizzo-wilson</usr:username><activity:object-type>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/person</activity:object-type></author><published>2013-07-25T18:50:59.377Z</published><updated>2013-07-25T18:50:59.377Z</updated><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-771?focusedCommentId=14964&amp;page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14964" rel="alternate" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/images/icons/issuetypes/genericissue.png" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/icon" title="Logic" /><link href="http://oncprojectracking.org/s/en_US-46i7uf-1988229788/6099/7/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:global-static/wiki-renderer.css" rel="http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/css" /><generator uri="http://oncprojectracking.org" /><atlassian:application>com.atlassian.jira</atlassian:application><activity:verb>http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/update</activity:verb><activity:object><id>urn:uuid:e9eeb6ef-dfba-3ea7-b55f-c9c3a6391cd5</id><title type="text">CQM-771</title><summary type="text">CMS188v3/NQF0147 Logic for No ED > NonICU > ICU path does not limit transfers to ICU to within 24hrs after arrival</summary><link rel="alternate" href="http://oncprojectracking.org/browse/CQM-771" /><activity:object-type>http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/types/issue</activity:object-type></activity:object><atlassian:timezone-offset>-0400</atlassian:timezone-offset></entry></feed>
```

The XSL file I am using us as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="feed/entry">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="updated"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the following error.

System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException
XSLT compile error. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you haven't defined the xsl namespace. Change

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

You also need to add an 'atom' namespace in order to make your 'for-each' and 'value-of' directives work, and you probably want to disable output escaping on your title fields to make the tags within them show up as markup. I suggeest this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Updated</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="atom:feed/atom:entry">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="atom:title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="atom:author"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="atom:updated"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```